# Regular Expression to filter subdomains starting with www

Tags: regex, https, filter, subdomain

I need a regular Expression that filters my subdomains starting with `www.` to redirect them to the same subdomain without the `www.`

So I need to filter urls with more then 3 dots in the domain name and start with `www.`:

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {

   if { [HTTP::uri] matches_regex "**?????????????**" } {

       //* do Something

   } else {

       //* do something else 

   }

}
```

Test case:

`www.subdomain.domain.com` should be converted to `subdomain.domain.com`.

I don't have any experience with regular expressions, so if somebody has a clue it would be helpful.

Comment: Please format your code properly.  4 spaces before each line of code with indents being an extra 4 spaces.  People will tend to downvote for improperly formatted code.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
^www(\.[^\/\?\n]*){3}
```

Tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/undVMs/2) with a few inputs.

---

**Explanations**

`^www` matches the three `w` at the beginning.

`[^\/\?\n]*` matches anything other than a marker of the end of the domain name (`?` may also end the domain name).

`(\.[^\/\?\n]*){3}` matches a dot followed by anything other than the end of the domain name, three times. This part will ensure you do have a subdomain (3 dots counting the `www.`).

Comment: It looks like this is more sophisticated then the "www\.*\.*\..+" i use for now. For now it's a bit abacadabra for me. I have to test if your regex does the right thing for me.

Comment: This is required if you don't want to mistake a dot in a url parameter for a subdomain. Think about `www.notasubdomain.com/test1.2/`.

Comment: @EdwinHendriks Is there anything you'd like me to detail, or a test case the regex doesn't handle properly?

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you need regular expressions to match this?

Easiest way you can accomplish what you want with regular expressions is:

```
^www\.
```

`^` is anchor to beginning of the string, `\.` is escaped dot, because dot in regular expressions means anything but newline character.

So basically this regex tells you, match me `www` which is right on the beginning of the string, afterwards there comes dot character.

You can see demo here: https://regex101.com/r/ZnVFaR/1

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me, because also a non-subdomain will be affected.